# Is it possible to customize Jenkins job status?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I am running a test suite (Java, Maven profiles) using a Jenkins job. I would like to update build status mid-execution to see if everything goes well so far.

The problem is, I want more build execution statuses (like Yellow/Warning) - is there any way, preferably without additional plug-ins, to add and customize their conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customize - yes, by using
`java -jar cli.jar set-build-result <stable|unstable|failed>` (for security enabled jenkins, see: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI) ; 
Add - no. :(

Answer (score 1):

I would say no you can't do it. But you can use another build strategy: split your job in smaller jobs, driven by another top level job.

Comment: Thanks, although I had already split the suite. The single test may run for quite a long time and I wondered whether it's possible to update his job status mid-way through.